# Is it possible to securely store data in JSONB column with Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, encryption, jsonb

I am pulling facebook user info from the graph api. I figured it would be easiest to store the whole blob in a JSONB column and pick specific keys out as needed with the Postgres JSONB operators.

Now I want to have that column encrypted as well, and it's dawning on that that maybe the jsonb approach isn't possible if I want to have the column encrypted. Is there any way to securely store data in a jsonb column?

Comment: secure from what type of access exactly? i.e. What threats are were you asked to secure against?

Comment: I don't want the values to be plain text since some of the data is personal information. So in case someone takes a db dump the personal information will be protected. This is really easy to do with individual columns, but this is the first time I've considered storing anything that i'd want secured as a JSONB. I'm guessing there's not really an elegant way and I should just bcrypt and salt the sensitive fields in their own column and forget JSONB here?

Comment: @RyanVincent BTW I can guess that the encrypted `JSON(B)` can not be used for the searching (how to search on the data which unavailable for the server?)

Comment: Yeah the data doesn't need to be searched. It's just being plucked out of the blob as needed. Stuff like first name, last name, email address. I was hoping I could keep the whole facebook user data secured in that column just for the flexibility. I was hoping that in the future if I add twitter login I could do the same with the returned twitter data. Say for instance they signed into a twitter account that used a different email address. The FB blob and Twitter blob could sit nicely in a single column for each service. Instead I have to deal with creating multiple columns for account types.

Comment: The issue with trying to encrypt stuff in the database, so that you the programmer can display it as required, means that your code has to have the password available to it. And if someone gets into the database then they almost certainly get the password as well ;-/ i.e. This exercise can provide 'peace of mind' but not actually provide any more actual data security from that attack ;-/

Comment: Lets remember that the `JSON` format is the simple text corresponding to the specific agreements. So it is easy to store the data as encrypted text and retrieve it using the user's key.

Comment: @Abelisto, but we don't store the user password - so we have to provide another means of showing the personal data on internal reports etc.? The user key is to allow them access to the system and just their personal data. which is not encrypted with their key? Unless we don't have access to it either. which is I think, a different requirement, than the one asked?

Comment: @RyanVincent IMO It is mutually exclusive demands: allow asses to the superuser(s) to show the data and disallow to export the data.

Comment: @Abelisto, yes! That is the point of this discussion. i.e. the OP needs to specify what threats are required to be defended against.

Comment: can DBs be built/compiled to not even have a dump capability?